# In Angular how do I call the link of an iframe video in the frontend

Tags: angular, iframe

I am trying to make a angular website for movie reviews. I want to add for each movie an "iframe" element with the "scr" being received out of the json file. how is it possible to do this without getting security warnings?

Below is an example with just the link with works fine but when I call the link from the json file is throws an error.

```
    <iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b_yvKh_ps18" 
    title="YouTube video player" 
    frameborder="0" 
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media;
    gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" 
    allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

I wanted to see the video from the iframe link fort each movie site I clicked on.